# Busybox USB Ethernet adapter

Tags: usb, ethernet, arm, busybox

I have an embedded device running busybox on an ARM 7 processor.  How would I go about using a USB -> Ethernet adapter for network connectivity?  Currently I only have a serial console.

The system sees the USB device with `lsusb`, but nothing shows up in `ifconfig`.  I suspect the drivers aren't loaded.

What is the easiest way to get this working?

Comment: more info about the devices, `uname -a`, is it something you compile your own kernel / drivers for, ...?

Answer (score 1):

Use lsusb get the device id, e.g. 138a:0017. Then look up the Linux drivers that support that device id for your architecture. Follow the instructions with said drivers. Reboot.